# jquery check all hidden elements for similarity of values and return boolean

Tags: jquery

How can I check a group of hidden fields for their values and if there are dissimilarities in their values, I will return false. But empty values and "False" should be treated as equal.  There are 3 possible values only, empty, True and False but I want to treat empty as False.

I want something like

```
var isTrue = true;

// is there a way to do this in jquery or similar to this?
var values = $("#group input:hidden").distinct().take(2);  
if(values.length == 2) {
    // only make it false if there is a true in the values.
    if(values[0] == 'True' || values[1] == 'True') {
        isTrue = false;
    }
}
```

output should be like

```
{values[0] = '', values[1] = 'False'} = true
{values[0] = 'True', values[1] = 'False'} = false
{values[0] = '', values[1] = 'True'} = false
```

Index in the index can be interchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following jQuery extension to your code.

```
(function( $ ){

    $.fn.haveSameValue = function() {

        var val = -1;
        var same = true;

        this.each(function() {
            var thisValue = ($(this).val()=="")?"False":$(this).val();
            if(val != thisValue && val != -1) {
                same = false;
                return false;
            }
            val = thisValue;
        });

        return same;
    };

})( jQuery );
```

Now you should be able to call `$('your-selector-here').haveSameValue()` which will return boolean `true` or `false` depending on if all the elements matched (by `'your-selector-here'`) have the same value or not.

Comment: actually I've answered my own question using $.each and yours is almost identical to my solution so I'll accept this answer.  And +1 for making it an extension.

Answer (score 1):

So ... basically you want to find out if there is more than one distinct string value in all of your hidden inputs (treating "" and "False" as the same)?

Something like this?

```
var prevVal = null;
var result = true;
$('#group input:hidden').each(function() {
    if(prevVal === null) {
        prevVal = $(this).val();
    } else if((prevVal === "True" && $(this).val() !== "True") || (prevVal === "" && ($(this).val() !== "" || $(this).val !== "False")) || (prevVal === "False" && ($(this).val() !== "" || $(this).val !== "False"))) {
        result = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: what does tripple equal '===' means and '!==' means?  I'm not very familiar with this boolean expression.

Comment: === means `equality without type coersion` ... so the content AND the type must be identical. !== is the negation